# How to message back in an OpenUrl Card Action?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am sending a cardAction with openURL where a user is supposed to click the button, follow instructions from said URL, and then report back the data. I would like a message displayed *when* the user clicks on the button, which is also when the URL is opened.

From what I have tested, I can only either ImBack or OpenUrl. Is there a way to do both in one CardAction?

```cs
var card = new SigninCard()
{
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
    {
        new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "Open a URL",
            Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
            Value = this.myURL,   
            DisplayText = "I want to show text when I open myURL but this text doesn't show",
        },
        new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "Message Back",
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
            Value = "MessageBackButtonClicked",
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: @tdurnford i am primarily testing on the emulator. goal is for it to work on webchat and directline (and facebook but i expect fb is handled differently altogether)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, each channel is responsible for handling user actions and most channels do not notify you when a user clicks on a link. However, in Web Chat, you can use the card action middleware to dispatch a backchannel event when the user clicks on an open URL action. Note, this will only work with Web Chat and not any other channel.

**Bot Framework Web Chat v4**

```
const cardActionMiddleware = ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
  const { cardAction: { type, value } } = action;
  if (type === 'openUrl') {
    dispatch({
      type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
      payload: {
        name: 'webchat/urlClickedEvent',
        value: `Navigating to ${value}`
      }
    });
  }
  return next(action);
}

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
  cardActionMiddleware,
  directLine,
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That did help! Good enough for webchat. I will explore other channel-specific ways to accomplish the same goal. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to get the title of the button which is having the url value?